# Different versions of Python 2.7 and Numpy produce different results for the same script

Tags: python-2.7, debugging, numpy

I have the following script:

```
import numpy as np

pin_info = {}

pinID = 4 
pin_info[pinID] = {}
pin_info[pinID]['matvols'] = np.array([0.4096,0.418,0.475,1.26])**2
pin_info[pinID]['matvols'][:-1] *= np.pi
pin_info[pinID]['matvols'][1:] -= pin_info[pinID]['matvols'][:-1]
print(pin_info)
```

My work machine uses Python 2.7.3 and Numpy 1.6.1 and gives the following result:

```
{4: {'matvols': array([ 0.52707179,  0.02183985,  0.68698199,  0.90061801])}
```

My local machine uses Python 2.7.11 and Numpy 1.10.4 and gives the following result:

```
{4: {'matvols': array([ 0.52707179,  0.02183985,  0.68698199,  0.87877816])}}
```

Unless I did my math incorrectly, the result produced by my local machine should be the right answer.  (The work machine gets the last entry of pin_info[4]['matvols'] wrong.)  However, I have no idea why my work machine produced the wrong answer.  Does anybody have any ideas?  I ran the exact same script on both machines.  I even md5sum-ed the files to make sure they were exactly the same.

EDIT: If you have a version of Python/Numpy that's close to 2.7.3/1.6.1, it would be great if you could try this script and see which answer you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

~ 0.87877816 would indeed be the correct result:

- Using [`calc`](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/calc/) (from
  [Ubuntu package
  `apcalc`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=apcalc)):

  ```sh
  calc '1.26^2 - 0.475^2 * pi()'
  ```

  ```
          ~0.87877815753380290057
  ```
- Using NumPy:

  ```
  In [6]: np.dot(np.array([0.475, 1.26]) ** 2 * np.array([np.pi, 1]), np.array([-1, 1]))
  Out[6]: 0.87877815753380306
  ```

Until just before the `-=` operation, everything works as expected:

```
In [1]: %cpaste
Pasting code; enter '--' alone on the line to stop or use Ctrl-D.
:import numpy as np
:
:pin_info = {}
:
:pinID = 4 
:pin_info[pinID] = {}
:pin_info[pinID]['matIDs'] = [1,4,5,6]
:pin_info[pinID]['matvols'] = np.array([0.4096,0.418,0.475,1.26])**2
:pin_info[pinID]['matvols'][:-1] *= np.pi
:--

In [2]: pin_info[pinID]['matvols']
Out[2]: array([ 0.52707179,  0.54891163,  0.70882184,  1.5876    ])
```

The slicing works, too:

```
In [3]: pin_info[pinID]['matvols'][1:]
Out[3]: array([ 0.54891163,  0.70882184,  1.5876    ])

In [4]: pin_info[pinID]['matvols'][:-1]
Out[4]: array([ 0.52707179,  0.54891163,  0.70882184])
```

Indeed, we can compute the correct result from here:

```
In [5]: pin_info[pinID]['matvols'][1:] - pin_info[pinID]['matvols'][:-1]
Out[5]: array([ 0.02183985,  0.15991021,  0.87877816])
```

But `-=` doesn't seem to do the right thing:

```
In [7]: pin_info[pinID]['matvols'][1:] -= pin_info[pinID]['matvols'][:-1]

In [8]: pin_info
Out[8]: 
{4: {'matIDs': [1, 4, 5, 6],
  'matvols': array([ 0.52707179,  0.02183985,  0.68698199,  0.90061801])}}
```

(Reproduced with Python 3.2.3 and NumPy 1.6.1 and with Python 2.7.3 and (also) NumPy 1.6.1.)

So what's going on here? Let's look at an integer example:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: x = np.array([5, 23, 42, 1000])

In [3]: x[1:] - x[:-1]
Out[3]: array([ 18,  19, 958])

In [4]: x[1:] -= x[:-1]

In [5]: x
Out[5]: array([  5,  18,  24, 976])
```

Can you see the pattern? It's processing the components left-to-right and using the already modified values for the computation of the subsequent components. We can emulate this without NumPy:

```
In [1]: x = [5, 23, 42, 1000]

In [2]: for i in range(len(x) - 1):
   ...:     x[i + 1] -= x[i]
   ...: 

In [3]: x
Out[3]: [5, 18, 24, 976]
```

I guess this was / is a bug in NumPy 1.6 that was fixed in some later version.

Comment: Ah okay, I see.  So I guess the conclusion is that there's a bug in Numpy with the -= operator?  I did some similar debugging analysis on my work machine, and I have the same conclusions as you.  Thank you for taking the time to go through it.